# How can collaborators push their changes to my repo in GitHub

Tags: eclipse, github, git

1. First I have created one project in Eclipse and committed to my GitHub using below commands:

   ```
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "first commit"
   git remote add origin URI of my repo
   git push -u origin master
   ```
2. Then I modified one file in Eclipse and committed to GitHub from Eclipse through creating remote and giving the remote URI of the repo.
3. I added my team member through add collaborator.
4. Then he downloaded my project and made a change in a file in Eclipse.

Now, how can he push that modified file to my GitHub repository from within Eclipse?

We have done one thing. He created a remote and gave the URI of my repo. But still we are unable to commit that file.

Comment: If that is a master branch, it is due to that the master is protected and only an owner can push some changes on the master branch. What error are you seeing?

Comment: Can you please post the error while pushing the code? Probably his local branch is not in sync with remote one.

Comment: error:" $ git push -u origin master
To https://github.com/Itcinfotech-Github/NewRepo.git
! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Itcinfotech-Github/NewRepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details."

Answer (score 1):

You need to [add your colleague as a collaborator](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/). This can be done in the desired GitHub repo via `Settings > Collaborators` (you need to type in your password again). Afterwards they have [those](https://help.github.com/articles/permission-levels-for-a-user-account-repository/#collaborator-access-on-a-repository-owned-by-a-user-account) permissions.

[image: Collaborator settings]

UPDATE

Sorry and good morning ;)

I overlooked that you already added your partner as a collaborator. Another possible reason for your situation could be in the `Temporary interaction limits` where you can, amongst others, limit the interaction with your repo to prior contributors.

[image: Temporary interaction limits]

If that doesn't help. Please add some more informations about your colleague's git logs.

UPDATE 2

@Rahul K regarding your comment (which you better add to your question, for faster recognition), your colleague first needs to integrate the remote changes via `git pull origin master` in order to be able to push his or her changes afterwards. But be aware that he or she might need to migrate any conflicts to files both of you applied changes to.

Best regards, David

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by cloning the repo in my local folder, adding the project to eclipse and changing the file committed.

Before that you have to add that person as a collaborator. So that he/she can clone your repo using the command below:

`git clone "Path to the repository"`

Comment: Everyone can clone your repo on GitHub, except when it's a private one. It seems your explanation misses some details.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I'll like to say this to help others that might still be facing this same issue.

I also faced this issue with a friend. I already made him a collaborator but he couldn't push. What we did to solve it was to clone the repo using the ssh url instead. Then we set up authentication in git with ssh. And we were able push successfully.

If you already cloned the repo with the usual HTTPS url, you can change the remote origin url using the `git remote set-url origin <url>` command but `url` here will be the ssh url.